# TypeScript error casting interface union field

Tags: typescript

This is the minimum code that produces the error:

```
interface A1 {
    type: "A1";
}
interface A2 {
    type: "A2";
}
type AU = A1 | A2;

function foo(obj1: AU) {
    const obj2: AU = {
        type: obj1.type
        /*
        Error TS2322:
        Type '{ type: "A1" | "A2"; }' is not assignable to type 'AU'.
            Type '{ type: "A1" | "A2"; }' is not assignable to type 'A2'.
            Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
            Type '"A1" | "A2"' is not assignable to type '"A2"'.
            Type '"A1"' is not assignable to type '"A2"'.
        */
    };
}
```

Is this a TypeScript error? (I posted this as issue #20889 on their GitHub)

Or am I somehow not using the tools properly?

Comment: this was tagged by the TypeScript team as intended behavior:  
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20896  
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20889

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When removing the type part from the `obj2` declaration - `const obj2 = { type: obj1.type }`, the type of `obj2` is set to `{ type: 'A1' | 'A2' }` and the code compiles correctly.

With this statement code also compiles correctly and the type is set to `AU`.

`let obj2 = { type: obj1.type } as AU`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that it tries to create an object with type "A1" | "A2" before assigning it to obj2.

so `{ type: "A1" | "A2"; }` is actually an unnamed type that exists temporarily (and which you can't assign to AU).

The usual use-case would be that both A1 and A2 have a couple of more attributes, which need to be initialized, so if you would create an if-then-else code, it would detect the type correctly as either {type: "A1";} or {type: "A";}

```
function foo(obj1: AU) {
    // No errors:
    if(obj1.type === 'A1') {
        const obj2: AU = { type: obj1.type /* further attributes here*/ };
    } else if(obj1.type === 'A2') {
        const obj2: AU = { type: obj1.type /* further attributes here*/ };
    }
}
```

I highly doubt that microsoft will do anything about this issue, since it probably would require some deeper rewriting on how the parser works.